Help writing a diagram of a mechanism with Tikz
This the code for the image
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usepackage{amsmath} 

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}

    % Axes
    \draw[->] (-1,0) -- (6,0) node[right] {$x$}; % x-axis
    \draw[->] (0,-1) -- (0,6) node[above] {$y$}; % y-axis
    
    % Large circle with center O and radius R
    \draw[thick] (0,0) circle (3.5); % Main large circle
    \node at (-0.3,-0.3) {$O$}; % Label O
    
    % Radius R from O to O_1 (dashed line)
    \draw[dashed] (0,0) -- (3,3) node[midway, above, sloped] {$R$};
    
    % Small circle with center O_1 and radius r
    \draw[thick] (3,3) circle (1); % Small circle
    \node at (3.1,2.8) {$O_1$}; % Label O_1

    % Point P on the large circle
    \filldraw[black] (3,3) circle (1pt);
    \node at (3.3,3.3) {$P$}; % Label P

    % Point M on small circle
    \filldraw[blue] (3,4) circle (2pt); % Point M at the top of the small circle
    \node at (3.2,4.1) {$M$}; % Label M

    % Arc for angle phi (ϕ) at point O
    \draw[->] (1,0) arc[start angle=0, end angle=45, radius=1] node[midway, right] {$\varphi$};

    % Arc for angle psi (ψ) on the small circle (O_1)
    \draw[->, red] (3.5,3) arc[start angle=0, end angle=90, radius=0.5] node[midway, right] {$\psi$};

    % Line segment r from O_1 to M
    \draw[dashed] (3,3) -- (3,4) node[midway, right] {$r$}; % Line r
    
    % Angular velocity (ω_0) at point O
    \draw[->] (1.5,1.5) arc[start angle=45, end angle=90, radius=1.5] node[midway, above] {$\omega_0$};
    
    % Ground pattern for the circle (hatching lines at the bottom)
    \draw[thick] (-1,-0.1) -- (-0.1,-0.1);
    \foreach \x in {-2,-1.5,...,-0.1} {
        \draw[thick] (\x,-0.1) -- (\x-0.3,-0.4);
    }

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}

and here is the image is generates

which is quite different from what I want:

Is out there a app where this kind of mechanical diagrams is easier to write?

"Easier to write" is a bit subjective -- if you want good results with any tool you just have to spend time learning and practicing.  But the only tricky thing in your diagram is finding the centre for the smaller circle.
For comparison, here is my effort in Metapost, which is an alternative drawing language that is built into lualatex and Context.   Follow the link above for tutorials and reference material.

You need to compile this source with lualatex.
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\begin{document}
\mplibtextextlabel{enable}
\begin{mplibcode}
beginfig(1);

% set up some parameters
numeric R, r; R = 89; r = 34;  % PostScript points 72 = 1in
numeric phi, psi; phi = 42; psi = 84;  % ° degrees

% the centres of the two circles
pair O, O'; 
O = origin; 
O' = (R+r, 0) rotated phi;

% make the circle paths
path C, c;
C = fullcircle scaled 2R shifted O;
c = fullcircle scaled 2r shifted O';

% define P and M. There are 8 points in a fullcircle path
% so you can from an angle to the "time" on the path by dividing
% by 360/8 = 45

pair P, M;
P = point phi / 45 of C;
M = point psi / 45 of c;

% define the two axes
path xx, yy;
xx = origin -- 1.4 R * right;
yy = origin -- 1.4 R * up;

% and the rays to show the radius in each circle
path RR, rr;
RR = O -- point 3.9 of C;
rr = O' -- point 3.9 of c;

% draw the axes
drawarrow xx; label.rt("$x$", point 1 of xx);
drawarrow yy; label.top("$y$",point 1 of yy);

% draw the radius rays
begingroup; 
  drawoptions(dashed withdots scaled 1/4 withcolor 1/2 blue);
  interim ahangle := 20; 
  drawdblarrow RR; 
  drawdblarrow rr; 
  label.top("$R$", point 1/2 of RR);
  label.top("$r$", point 1/2 of rr);
  drawoptions();
endgroup;

% do the angle marks
draw O' -- O' + 20 right;
drawoptions(withcolor 2/3 red);
  draw fullcircle scaled 25 shifted O  cutafter (O--P);
  draw fullcircle scaled 20 shifted O' cutafter (O'--M);
  label("$\phi$", O  + 20 dir 1/2 phi);
  label("$\psi$", O' + 16 dir 1/2 psi);
drawoptions();

% do the hatching around the big circle
for t=4.5 step 1/8 until 6.25:
  draw (origin -- 20 dir 240) shifted point t of C;
endfor

% and the strange thing in the middle
path thing;
thing = (left--right) scaled 10 shifted O shifted 10 down;
draw thing;
draw point 1/8 of thing -- origin -- point 7/8 of thing;
for t=0 step 1/6 until 1+eps:
  draw (origin -- 3 dir 240) shifted point t of thing;
endfor

% draw the circles and the line from O to M
draw C;
draw c;
draw O -- P -- O' -- M;

% finally add some labels.
labeloffset := 5;
dotlabel.ulft("$O$", O);
dotlabel.lrt ("\!$O'$", O');
dotlabel.bot ("\strut $P$\,", P);
dotlabel.top ("$M$", M);

endfig;
\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}


How can I incorporate this in the rest of my code if it has to be run in lulatex?

Well you could switch to lualatex for the whole document, but if you are not ready for that, then compile the diagram into a standalone PDF and use \includegraphics to include it in your main document.  That's what the standalone document class is for...

This is a MWE that shows some of the main functionalities you are looking for; you should be able to elaborate on this to complete your diagram.
The key points are

the use of sine and cosine

the foreach loop with the ++ option

the use of tkz-euclide to make the angle.



\documentclass[tikz, border=0.2cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

% axes
\coordinate (O) at (0,0);
\draw[->] (O) -- (2,0);
\draw[->] (O) -- (0,2);

% inner circle
\fill (O) circle[radius=0.062];
\newcommand{\innerRadius}{0.75}
\draw (O) circle[radius=\innerRadius];

% outercircle
\newcommand{\varTheta}{35}
\newcommand{\outerRadius}{0.3}
\coordinate (outerCenter) at ({\innerRadius*cos(\varTheta)+\outerRadius*cos(\varTheta)},{\innerRadius*sin(\varTheta)+\outerRadius*sin(\varTheta)});
\fill (outerCenter) circle[radius=0.062];
\draw (outerCenter) circle[radius=\outerRadius];

% hash marks
\foreach \varAngle in {190,195,...,270}{
\draw ({\innerRadius*cos(\varAngle)},{\innerRadius*sin(\varAngle)}) -- ++(-0.2,-0.2);
}

% an angle 
\draw (O) -- (outerCenter);
\coordinate (auxillaryX) at (1,0);
\draw pic["$\phi$",draw,-,angle eccentricity=1.8, angle radius=0.2cm]{angle=auxillaryX--O--outerCenter};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}



In retrospect, I think that the hash marks are better done with a pattern, so that they can be equidistant. Just a suggestion.
